# Всем привет. Не получается вывести картинки на HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
@font-face  {
    font-family: "poller_oneregular";
    src: url("... /fonts/pollerone/pollerone-webfont.eot");
    src: url("... /fonts/pollerone/pollerone-webfont.eot?#iefix")
    format("embedded-opentype"),
    src: url("... /fonts/pollerone/pollerone-webfont.woff")
    format("woff"),
    src: url("... /fonts/pollerone/pollerone-webfont.ttf")
     format("truetype"),
        url("... /fonts/pollerone/pollerone-webfont.svg#poller_oneregular")
     format("svg");
}

@font-face {
    font-family : "leckerli-oneregular";
    src: url("... /fonts/leckerlione/leckerlione-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("... /fonts/leckerlione/leckerlioner-regular-webfont.eot&#iefix")
    format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("... /fonts/leckerlione/leckerlioner-regular-webfont.woff")
    format("woff")
         url("... /fonts/leckerlione/leckerlioner-regular-webfont.ttf")
    format("truetype")
        url("... /fonts/leckerlione/leckerlioner-regular-webfont.svg#leckerli_oneregular")
    format("svg");
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 960px;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    color: #252525;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p a {
color: #252525;
text-decoration: underline;
}

p a:hover{
color: 898989;
}

#header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 44px 0 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
}

#header a.logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 340px;
}

#header a.logo  img{
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 56px 0 0;
}

#header ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 19px;
}

#header ul li a{
    color: #252525;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Arial-Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header ul li a:hover, #header ul li.selected a{
    color: rebeccapurple;
}

#body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#body h1{
    color: red;
    display: inline;
    font-family: poller_oneregular;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#body h1 span{
    background: #252525;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15 28 12px;
}

#body > div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;
}

#body > div img{
    border: 2px solid #252525;
    margin: 24px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#body > div .arcticle{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 30px 0;
    width: 560px;
}

#body > div .acticle h2{
    font-family: "Arial-Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}

#body > div.arcticle h3{
    color: #252525;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#body > div .arcticle h4{
    background: #252525;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Arial-Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 8px 27px 10px;
}

#body > div .arcticle p{
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}

#body div ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 24px 10px 0;
    width: 940px;
}

#body div ul li{
    border: 2px solid#1a1a1a;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

#body div ul li .figure{
    border-right: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 376px;
}

#body div ul li img{
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#body div ul i .figure:hover img{
    opacity: 1;
}

#body div ul li div{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 63px 0 20px;
    width: 558px;
}

#body div ul li div h3{
    color: #252525;
    font-family: "Arial-Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#body div ul li div p{
    padding: 30px 30px 18px;
}

#body div ul li a.more{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #252525;
    font-family: "Arial-Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:0;
    padding: 8px 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#body div ul li div a.more:hover{
    color: #252525;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #252525;
}

#body #featured{
    margin: 0 0 13px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#body #featured img{
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
}

#body #featured div{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -420px;
    margin-top: -171px;
    padding: 0 0 0 470px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 490px;
}

#body #featured div h2{
    background: #abf;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:poller_oneregular;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 18px;
    padding: 23px 27px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#body #featured div span{
    background: #252525;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 7px 0;
    padding: 12px 27px;
}

#body #fetured div a{
    background: #0ba39c;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    padding: 26px 27px 22px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;    
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

#body #fetured div a:hover{
    background: #299000;
}

#body > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 24px 0 0 ;
    width: 960px;
}

#body > ul li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

#body > ul li a{
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-family: poller_oneregular;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#body > ul li a img{
    border: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#body > ul li a:hover img{
    opacity: 1;
}

#body > ul li a span {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 33px 0 0;
}

#body form{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px 0 0;
    width: 620px;
}

#body form input, #body form textarea {
    border: 2px solid #252525;
    color: #252525;
    font-family:Arial, Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 37px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 596px;
}

#body form textarea {
    height: 175px;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
}

#body form #send {
    background: #f30a0a;
    color: rgb(230, 15, 15);
    font-family:Arial, Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 28px;
    width: auto;
}

#body form #send:hover{
    background: rgb(132, 77, 221);
    color: #f01a1a;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#footer {
    background: rgb(47, 2, 53);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
}

#footer div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px; 
}

#footer div p {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 70px;
}

#footer div ul {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 256px;
}

#footer div ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 44px;
}

#footer div ul li #facebook {
    background-position:  0 -44px;
}

#footer div ul li #facebook:hover {
    background-position: -44px -44px;
}

#footer div ul li #instagram {
    background-position: 0 -44px;
}
#footer div ul li #instagram:hover {
    background-position: -44px -44px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initialscale = 1.0">
    <title>Гироскутер</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "style_giroskuter.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript" href = "slider.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "header">
            <h1>Гироскутеры какие угодно</h1>
            <ul id = "navigation">
                <li class = "selected">
                    <a href = "index.html">Главная</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "contact.html">Контакты</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "about.html">Доставка и оплата</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "gallery.html">Каталог</a>
                </li>
                     </ul>
    </body>
<div id = "body">

    <h2>IO CHIC Smart-LS 9 Black</h2>
    <img src = "image9.jpg" alt = "">
         
    <p align = "left">Описание</p>
    <p align = justify>Гироскутер этот может ездить. Вот. Очень интересно.</p>
    <p align = justify>А еще он имеет колеса, ручку, механизмы и так далее.</p>
    <p align = "left">Характеристика</p>
    
    <p>Максимальная скорость:20 км\ч
    <p>Максимальная нагрузка:120кг
    <p>Максимальная мощность:2000 Вт
    <p align = "left">Цена</p>
    <br><b>5000 Руб</b>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href = "catalog.html">
                <img scr = "image9.jpg" >
                <br>IO CHIC Smart-LS 9 Black
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
                
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

            <h2>Преимущества:</h2>
            <p><span>Экологичность</span>
            <p><span>Экономичность</span>
            <p><span>Компактность</span>
            <p><a href = "Buy.html" class = "more">Купить</a>

    </div>
    </div>

    <ul>
    <li>
            <a href = "catalog.html">
        <img scr = "image20.jpg" >
            <br>IO CHIC Smart-LS 20 Yellow
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
            <a href = "catalog.html">
        <img scr = "image6.jpg" >
                <br>IO CHIC Smart-LS 6 White
            </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id ="footer">
    <div>
        <p>&copy;2022 Магазин гироскутеров</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href = "https://www.facebook.com" id = "facebook">facebook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                <a href = "https://www.instagram.com" id = "instagram">instagram</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
                
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пробелы до и после `=` зачем стоят?

Comment: это на работу кода ни как не влияет

Comment: стоят потому что мне так нравится

Comment: @ВикторГуд ,браузеру не нравятся пробелы перед и после, потому и картинки не выводятся

Comment: щас тогда проверю и напишу

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: в консоли прописывает что путь прописан неправильно

Comment: о каких картинках речь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вы посмотрите как вы пишете путь, если файл изображения находится в той же директории что и html документ путь должен быть `<img scr="./image6.jpg" >`
Так же в стилях у вас что то неясное с путями, почему 3 точки?
Можно использовать лишь: `./` - текущая директория. `../` - выйти из текущей директории.
Прочтите гайд по путям http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki

Comment: я первый раз вижу чтоб ставили три точки, пробел и потом путь. Пробел это символ 0.0

Comment: `./` ставить не обязательно.